# select all and some on the same query

Tags: mysql

I have this schema

```
Table Foo
user_id | time_dif | tool
1       | 1        | flurry
1       | 0        | flurry
1       | 15       | flurry
1       | 4        | flurry
1       | 5        | topler
```

what i want is a query that does this two at the same time, unfortunately i don't know how to combine them...

```
select count (user_id), tool  from Foo group by tool;
> 4 , flurry
> 1 , topler

select count(user_id) from Foo where time_diff > 2 group by tool 
> 2 , flurry
> 1 , topler
```

I want a query that combine those two together and gave me something like this:

```
> 4 , 2 , flurry
> 1 , 1 , topler
```

note: I want both results to be returned in the same row...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  tool,
  COUNT(user_id) cnt,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN time_diff>2 THEN user_id END) cnt2
FROM
  Foo
GROUP BY
  tool
```

CASE WHEN will return user_id if time_diff is >2, otherwise it will be NULL, and COUNT will only count non null values. Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14550/2).